# Probability Homework Puzzle

Tags: probability

A box 1 contains 5 white and 6 black balls. Another box II contains 6 white balls and 4 black balls. A box is selected at random and then a ball is drawn from it.

(i) What is the probability that the ball drawn will be white ?

(ii) Given that the ball drawn is white, what is the probability that it came from box I?

My logic: (i)  $\frac{1}{2}*\left (\frac{5}{11}+\frac{6}{10}\right )$

This does not match with the given answer, which is $\frac{83}{110}$

Part (ii) will depend on part(i) as it is conditional. $P\left(box_1|white\right)=\frac{P(box_1\: and\: white)}{P(white)}$

Part(ii) answer is $\frac{25}{83}$

Any hints ?

Comment: Your answer looks correct. (i) 58/110 and (ii) 25/58

Comment: There is a type in the solution